# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT while connecting to host

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to nodejs and socket.io i try to make a simple chat through socket.io, connecting with my database.But have an issue while am connecting to host using node.js. I am using amazon server. Please help me to solve this.
    This is my code :-

```
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var express = require('express');
    var config = require('./config/config');
    var io = require('socket.io')();
    var openDB = require('json-file-db');
    var db = openDB('db.json');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var gcm = require('node-gcm-service');
    var apn = require('apn');

    var app = express();
    app.listen(config.HTTP_PORT); // 3000
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    io.listen(config.SOCKET_PORT);//7777

    console.log("Server is up");
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({

    host : 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'my_password',
    database : 'my_db'
    });

    connection.connect(function(error){
        if(!!error)
        {
            console.log(error);
            console.log('Error');
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('connected');
        }
    });



Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/var/www/html/server1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:425:13)
at Socket.g (events.js:286:16)
at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:185:7)
at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:333:8)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:228:11)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/html/server1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/html/server1/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (/var/www/html/server1/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
at Object. (/var/www/html/server1/app1.js:35:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
syscall: 'connect',
fatal: true
```

Comment: Are you accessing remotely  mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open remote mysql port (3306 by default).